# Do bands perform "live at somewhere" or "live in somewhere" or ...?

Tags: sentence

I saw a video (of a band performing on a stage, typical "live performance", inside a theatre) which had this title:

> (Band name), Live at (Town) Theatre

But it occured to me that `in` might fit:

> (Band name), Live in (Town) Theatre

One of my peers also pointed out (NOTE: None of us is a native speaker!) that `'s` should be there, which would lead to two more "options":

> (Band name), Live at (Town)'s Theatre
>
> (Band name), Live in (Town)'s Theatre

Which one is the "proper" way of saying it ?

*Bonus question: "Theatre"/"Theater" ? I read there is no actual difference other than the former being enGB and the latter being enUS ?*

Comment: I'd also like to rant (in a comment, since it's only marginally relevant) about it being hard to distinguish "live" as in "live performance" from "live" as in "to live somewhere" when using google...

Comment: No, we use "at" for this. You'd use "in" if it were the area/town being named rather than the building. Yes re the spelling of "theatre". As for the apostrophe-s, I think that just depends on what the name of the theatre actually is.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_at_Red_Rocks_8.15.95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[band name] is performing live at [theatre's name]
Example: 
Iron maiden is performing at Air Canada Centre

or

[band name] is performing live in [country]

Iron Maiden is performing in Japan

Comment: Spot on, thanks for the examples. (*up the irons*)

Comment: Up the irons \m/

Answer (score 1):

When you are mentioning a city/town name , then 'in' should be used but when you are mentioning a particular place within the city or town then 'at' should be used.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, `live *IN* that town / live *AT* that place (inside the town)` but not `live *AT* that place (inside of town)` ?

Comment: Yes , you live in New York but you stay at your place.

Answer (score 0):

It should be 'Live at Theater' NOT 'Live in Theater'. Compare this with 'Live in London" but not 'Live at London'